# Ionic 1 project - none of the cli commands work

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 1 project and the latest cli (3.12.0).
First I've tried "ionic cordova run ios" - then it stucked and nothing else happened. Then I've tried to remove ios and android platform and add again, but none of the cli-commands work (without error, only stuck).

Only "ionic serve" work.

**I've deleted the following folders/files:**

- hooks
- node_modules
- platforms
- plugins
- package.lock
- yarn.lock

**then i ran the following commands:**

- yarn (install) -> worked
- ionic cordova platform add ios -> only the platforms-folder were created but nothing else

**here is my "ionic info"**

cli packages: (/Users/.../node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : none
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.1
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.4.0
npm        : 5.4.2
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously there was an problem with the folder permissions, because of the update to macOS High Sierra.

I‘ve fixed this with the following:

- in the terminal „cd“ to the folder where your project is („cd /Users/username/projects“)
- Own your project folder recursively („chown -R YOUR_USERNAME YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER“)

After this i was able to run the Ionic commands again.